# Entity Linking with Wikipedia and Wikidata on spaCy v3.7

Tags: python, nlp, wikidata, spacy-3, entity-linking

I'm planning to perform custom training with spaCy for entity linking using Wikidata. Could you provide guidance on creating a KnowledgeBase, especially since the latest spaCy version needs InMemoryLookupKB?

I'm also considering refactoring the code in the current GitHub repository (https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/master/nel-wikipedia) to match the latest version.
Do you think this is a good approach, or is there a simpler way? Any helpful tips or tricks would be welcome.